# swift 3.1.1 ERROR extra argument '{property}' in call

Tags: class, inheritance, swift3, properties, init

I was testing out inheritance in Swift 3 and ran into an unexpected error. No matter how I alter the `super.init()` call, I can't make the error trace less problematic than this.

I have read through the documentation and other similar posts here on SO, but they don't have any examples of this particular problem. I am trying to create a class with properties that are either variable or constant and then creating another class that inherits from the first class and adds new properties.

The error comes from my subclass's init function: I set the new properties first, then call `super.init()` with the superclass's appropriate arguments. Swift then tells me that the third parameter "birthday" is an "extra argument."

Is there some sort of problem between my superclass having three properties and my subclass having two? I can't think of any other problem that could throw an error like this. Not sure which part is confusing me.

Here's my code:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    let birthday: String

    init(name: String, age: Int, birthday: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.birthday = birthday
    }
}

class Student: Person {
    var isEnrolled: Bool
    var numberOfClasses: Int

    init(isEnrolled: Bool, numberOfClasses: Int) {
        self.isEnrolled = isEnrolled
        self.numberOfClasses = numberOfClasses
        super.init(name: name, age: age, birthday: birthday) {
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.birthday = birthday
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer does not have a closure, so naturally, your approach cannot work. It says `birthday` is an extra argument, because the (non-existent) closure is the fourth argument in the list.

`Student`'s initializer does not know what `name`, `age` or `birthday` is. You should include those parameters in the initializer as well and call `super.init` at the end.

```
init(name: String, age: Int, birthday: String, isEnrolled: Bool, numberOfClasses: Int) {
    self.isEnrolled = isEnrolled
    self.numberOfClasses = numberOfClasses

    super.init(name: name, age: age, birthday: birthday)
}
```